# how to reverse an if condition in php?

Tags: php, if-statement

hi I am trying to see if i can reverse this if statement so that I can have an if condition which lists results only if the user session is not the user id.

I'm brand new to mysql and php and would really appreciate if someone could show me what i need to do

here's the if statement I'm trying reverse so if $user['id'] is not $_SESSION['user_id']

```
if ($user['id'] == $_SESSION['user_id']){
```

I've tried this: (doesn't work and brings up a syntax error)

```
if (!isset($user['id'] == $_SESSION['user_id'])){
```

Comment: What does this have to do with `mysql`?

Comment: Actually, there's nothing to do with mysql, but reversed condition : if ($user['id'] != $_SESSION['user_id']){

Comment: http://php.net/language.operators.comparison ...

Comment: != ? $user['id'] != $_SESSION['user_id']

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly simple and actually [basic PHP stuff](http://php.net/language.operators.comparison):

`if ($user['id'] != $_SESSION['user_id'] )`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Sturb's answer you can also reverse the variables:

```
if($_SESSION['user_id'] != $user['id'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check using if condition

```
if(!$user['id']==$_SESSION['user_id'])
```

Comment: This isn't very readable, I would suggest changing to

    `if( $user['id'] != $_SESSION['user_id'] )`